# Using a non-laravel package on Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, package, laravel-4

Is it possible to include a package that was not specifically designed for L4 in the framework?
If so, how is it done? I know I need to add the package to my `composer.json` which adds it to the `vendor` folder, but can I register it somehow in the `providers` array? are there any other steps necessary?

I would like to use the [Google checkout package](https://packagist.org/packages/tvr/googlecheckout) originally designed for Yii

Answer (score 100, accepted):

**Using third party composer packages with Laravel 4**

When developers create composer packages, they should map the auto-loading using PSR-0 or PSR-4 standards. If this is not the case there can be issues loading the package in your Laravel application. The PSR-0 standard is:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "Acme": "src/" }
    }
}
```

And the PSR-4 standard:

```
{
    "autoload": {
         "psr-4": { "Acme\\": "src/" }
    }
}
```

Basically the above is a standard for telling composer where to look for name-spaced files. If you are not using your own namespaces you dont have to configure anything else.

***SCENARIO 1***

**PSR-0 standard following packages (with autoload classmap) in Laravel**

This is a simple one, and for example i will use the facebook php sdk, that can be found:

https://packagist.org/packages/facebook/php-sdk

**Step 1:**

Include the package in your composer.json file.

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.0.*",
    "facebook/php-sdk": "dev-master"
}
```

**Step 2:**

```
run: composer update
```

**Step 3:**

Because the facebook package uses a class map its working out of the box, you can start using the package instantly. (The code example below comes straight from a normal view. Please keep your logic out from views in your production app.)

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'secret',
    'secret' => 'secret'
));
var_dump($facebook); // It works!
```

***SCENARIO 2***

For this example i will use a wrapper from the instagram php api. Here there need to be made some tweaks to get the package loaded. Lets give it a try!
The package can be found here:

https://packagist.org/packages/fishmarket/instaphp

**Step 1:**

Add to composer .json

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.0.*",
    "fishmarket/instaphp": "dev-master"
}
```

Then you can update normally (composer update)

Next try to use the package like you did with the facebook package. Again, this is just code in a view.

```
$instagramconfig = array(
    'client_id' => 'secret',
    'client_secret'=> 'secret',
    'access_token' => 'secret'
);

$api = Instaphp::Instance(null, $instagramconfig);                
var_dump($api); // Epic fail!
```

If you try the above example you will get this error:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'Instaphp' not found in ...
```

So we need to fix this issue. To do this we can examine the instagram composer.json, that has its autoload diffrent than the facebook php sdk had.

```
"autoload": {
         "psr-0": { "Instaphp": "." }
    }
```

Compared to the facebook composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": ["src"]
    }
```

(Composer handles different kinds of autoloading, from files and class-maps to PSR. Take a look at your `vendor/composer/` folder to see how its done.)

Now we will have to load the class, manually. Its easy, just add this (top of your controller, model or view):

```
use Instaphp\Instaphp;
```

composer dump-autoload, and it works!

**step2 (optional)**

Another method is (if you dont want to use the "use" statement, you can simply tell composer to look for the files straight from your code. Just change the Instance like so:

```
// reference the name-spaced class straight in the code
$api = Instaphp\Instaphp::Instance(null, $instagramconfig); 
var_dump($api); // It works
```

However I suggest using the `use`statement to make it clear to other developers (and your future self) what (external) classes/packages are used in the program.

***SCENARIO 3***

Here we use the Laravels built in IOC container to register service providers. Please note that some packages might not be suitable for this method. I will use the same Instagram package as in scenario 2.

**Quick and dirty**

If you don't care about design patterns and service providers you can bind a class like this:

```
App::bind('Instaphp', function($app)
{
    return new Instaphp\Instaphp;
});
```

And you resolve it like this.

```
App::make('Instaphp');
```

**Quick and dirty end**

If you're working on a bigger project, and you make use of interfaces you should probably abstract the bindings further.

**Step 1:**

Create a folder inside your app folder, for example a 'providers' folder.

```
app/providers
```

Make sure Laravel auto-loads that folder, you can pass in some additional info to composer.json, like this:

```
"autoload": {

    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "app/providers" // this was added
    ]

},
```

Now create a File inside the new folder called Instagram.php and place this inside:

```
 <?php

    use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

    class InstagramServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('Instaphp', function()
        {
            return new Instaphp\Instaphp;
        });

    }

}
```

Now run composer dump-autoload again, and you can use the package. Note that the instagram package has a `final private function __construct()`, this means you cannot use that package outside the original class without changing the construct method to public. I'm not saying this is a good practice, and i suggest to use the scenario 2, in the case of the instagram package.

Anyway, after this you can use the package like this:

```
$instagramInstance = App::make('Instaphp');

$instagramconfig = array(
    'client_id' => 'secret',
    'client_secret'=> 'secret',
    'access_token' => 'secret'
 );

$instagram = new $instagramInstance();
$userfeed = $instagram->Users->feed($instagramconfig);

var_dump($userfeed); // It works!
```

Comment: This is still not clicking for me.  I'm trying to install the FirePHP package. After adding it to composer.json and running composer install the files show up in vendor/firephp . I've tried creating the provider folder and creating a FirePHPServiceProvider file but I'm not able to figure out hot to properly register it. I also don't understand the relationship to the vendor/firephp/firephp-core/lib/FirePHPCore/FirePHP.Class.php file. What am I missing?  Should I be starting a new question?

Comment: check your composer.lock file, is everything loaded correctly in the file? firephp uses lib so the path should be

 "classmap": [
    "lib/FirePHPCore/FirePHP.class.php",
    "lib/FirePHPCore/fb.php"
]

The relationship is just where the classes are, usually they are kept in a src or lib folder. Just try to install and then dump the instance, to check if laravel is loading it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  It's getting loaded correctly in my composer.lock file.  I'm having trouble understanding what to set up in the ServiceProvider file and how to properly reference that file in the providers array of the app file.  For example, in the register function am I binding a 'FirePHP' function or the 'fb' function? I don't know why this isn't clicking, I've read the Laravel documentation, I've read everything in code happy, etc.

Comment: Ok, I figured out one of my problems - I needed to add "app/providers" to the composer.json autoload.  Still murky at best on what I would need to register?  'FirePhp', or 'fb', etc?

Comment: Ok, I got it to work.  In my register statement I simply put $this->app->bind('FirePHP', function() { return new FirePHP; }); Although it's working I would like to understand how the IoC container knows that 'FirePHP' relates to  "lib/FirePHPCore/FirePHP.class.php" and "lib/FirePHPCore/fb.php". How does it know what I'm asking for?  I feel it would make more sense if I did something like $this->app->bind('FirePHP.class.php'... or if I had added use "lib/FirePHPCore/FirePHP.class.php" and use "lib/FirePHPCore/fb.php" to the top of the FirePHP file I created to register with IoC.

Comment: Can we make the answer even better by giving example code for steps #1, #3 (just a little more) #5 and #7?  As well as a brief explanation for what $this->app->bind does.  I understand to #5 and #7.  As stupid as it sounds, I can't use it.

Comment: Thank you. I will be worshiping you as my new golden god for this post.

Comment: Haha! Glad to be of help!

Comment: I had this problem so I created my own package: https://packagist.org/packages/p3in/firephp I also intend on continuing work on this, it's absolutely invaluable to my work!

Comment: when stackoverflow answers are more thorough than the laravel documentation

Answer (score 1):

Add `"tvr/googlecheckout": "dev-master"` this to your `composer.json`.

Run `composer install`, then you can use the IoC container. Some code examples can be found in the official docs for Laravel 4: http://four.laravel.com/docs/ioc#basic-usage

Comment: Thanks. I did some research on the IoC container and DI, but I still don't understand how to load a class/library which doesn't follow the Laravel service provider's lines. If I simply call it from my Payments controller constructor, I get a class not found error. I'd appreciate an example