# Laravel 4 using vendor classes

Tags: class, laravel, laravel-4, vendor

I have installed Laravel 4 after using 3, love it.
I used to be able to use the Zend framework as such:

```
       $yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
```

for instance

I have used composer to install Zend and everything is installed in the Vendor folder..

Problem:

How to address the individual classes i.e. Zend Gdata etc.

I can't find any documentation on calling classes from a vendor in L4.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190772/using-a-non-laravel-package-on-laravel-4

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take a look at your vendor\composer\autoload_classmap.php file. In there you will find a list of all vendor classes that are being autoloaded. I think all classes will have to be called using their full namespaced name.

E.g.

I'm using Zizaco's Entrust package. This is what it looks like in the vendor\composer\autoload_classmap.php file.

```
'Zizaco\\Entrust\\Entrust' => $vendorDir . /zizaco/entrust/src/Zizaco/Entrust/Entrust.php',
```

If I wanted to access the Entrust.php class I have to call

```
$en = new Zizaco\Entrust\Entrust();
```

Alternatively you could alias certain classes in your app\config\app.php file.

E.g.

```
'Ent'         => 'Zizaco\Entrust\Entrust'
```

In your case you'll need to do something like this:

```
$yt = new Zend\namespace\Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
```

Comment: I did figure it out...I accepted and one up'ed for still responding

Comment: Thanks again...that was the issue...I just had to dig a little :)