# Laravel 4 Using Zend Framework 1

Tags: zend-framework, laravel, barcode, vendor

I want to use some components from Zend framework with laravel 4, e.g. barcode.

I installed the barcode component via composer.

But how can I use it?

If I use this example from Zend.com:

```
 $barcodeOptions = array('text' => 'ZEND-FRAMEWORK')
 $rendererOptions = array();


 $imageResource = Zend_Barcode::factory(
      'code39', 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions
 )->draw();
```

I got an exception that Zend_Barcode was not found.

I also tried to use namespace `Zend\Barcode\Zend_Barcode::factory()`
(this tip is from [Laravel 4 using vendor classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398087/laravel-4-using-vendor-classes) )

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you dump the auto loader? `composer dump-autload`

Comment: Yes i did dump the autoloader. I also tried to delete the vendor folder und install all new.