# Laravel - How to use a vendor class?

Tags: php, class, laravel, laravel-4, vendor

I want to use Mobile Detect on m routes.php file. I have added the package as a require in composer.json and it's installed in the vendor file. How can I use it now?

I tried this answer and no luck because the class wasn't found: [Laravel 4 using vendor classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398087/laravel-4-using-vendor-classes)

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
        "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

EDIT: I tried using this one: https://github.com/jenssegers/Laravel-Agent, but the alias never worked saying the class was not found.

Comment: Can you try running `php artisan dump-autoload`, `composer dump-autoload`, or `php composer.phar dump-autoload`?

Comment: I did this. now what?

Comment: That had a chance of fixing it, I'm assuming you are still getting class not found? Make sure you don't have namespacing issues (see @MatthewBrown).

Comment: Sam, I think his question was more about namespacing and how/what to use to call it from a basic standpoint.  This is my question also.   I'm looking to @Matthews answer.

Answer (score 9):

This package is `PSR-0` namespaced.  Looking at the git repo, it appears to be `Detection\MobileDetect` **though you will want to make sure this is indeed the correct namespace**.  Have you tried adding the proper namespace to your `routes.php` file?

```
use Detection\MobileDetect as MobileDetect;
```

or you can reference the proper namespace inline.  Here is an example:

```
$detect = new Detection\MobileDetect\Mobile_Detect;
$deviceType = ($detect->isMobile() ? ($detect->isTablet() ? 'tablet' : 'phone') : 'computer');
```

If this doesn't work for you, you may be able to get away by adding it to your `composer.json` classmap:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": ["/vendor/serbanghita/namespaced/"],
}
```

Of course, fill in the proper path then run a `composer dump-auto`.

Comment: How do I use it after that? I tried `$detect = new MobileDetect();` under that and got `Class 'Detection\MobileDetect' not found`

Comment: Try the classmap portion of the answer, make sure to fill in the proper path to the Mobile_Detect.php folder

Comment: I added this to the classmap: `"/vendor/mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib/namespaced/Detection/MobileDetect.php",` and `MobileDetect.php` has a namespace of `Detection`. Tried `use Detection as MobileDetect;` and still get a class error.

Comment: if you added it to your classmap, and ran a `composer dump-auto` you should be able to reference the Class directly, without `use namespace`.  What happens now when you try `$detect = new Mobile_Detect;`

Comment: I'm doing `$detect = new Detection;` and same class not found error. MobileDetect.php has `namespace Detection`.

Comment: Right, but when you are autoloading the class, you need not worry about namespaces.  Try: `$detect = new Mobile_Detect;`  Also, can you update your answer with your classmap?

Comment: I tried `Mobile_Detect` as you suggested before `Detection` and no luck. See my edit at then end of the OP, would that be an easier fix? I can't get that to work either.

Answer (score 2):

I was also struggling with the mobile detection in Laravel, but I found the solution! This is from the beginning (incl. installation):

- in the terminal in your Laravel project folder:

  ```
  $ composer require mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib
  ```
- in a Middleware file for mobile detection:

  ```
  use Mobile_Detect;

  ...

  $detect = new Mobile_Detect;

  if ($detect->isMobile()) var_dump('is mobile');
  else var_dump('is not mobile');
  ```

And you are ready to go ;)