# Laravel 4 Packages

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm having a problem. What I'm trying to do is create basic package for geolocation. I'm using workbench to create the package and there is only one source and one config file. Plus the API that I'm using. Here's my GeoLocation class

```php
<?php namespace EvansEric\GeoLocate;

require('ip2locationlite.class.php');


class GeoLocate{

    public function gip()
    {
        echo 'test';
    }

    public function gCountry()
    {
        echo 'test';
    }

}
```

And here's my config file

```php
<?php

return array(

    /**
    *
    * @ Set the API Key obtained from ipinfodb.com
    */

    'key'   =>      '',

    /**
    *
    * @ Set Refresh rate. Set to 0 by default
    */

    'refresh'   =>  0,

    /**
    *
    * @ Set default location
    */

    'default_location'  =>  '216.110.94.228',
);
```

I have my package register in the app config on the main application. EvansEric\GeoLocate

But I can't use it in my application. Keeps saying it can't find class. But I'm looking at the class and I know it's there. Please help.

Comment: Or better yet does anyone have a link to some tutorials for creating packages?

Comment: http://four.laravel.com/docs/packages#creating-a-package

Comment: Thanks but I've been there. I meant someone who explains whats going on. And how to reference the package for use after creation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15225170/769237