# TCPDF class not found in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, tcpdf

I user following steps to use TCPDF, but I get `Class tcpdf not found` when try to make object of tcpdf class. If someone point where I am wrong or missing any step:
1. Added `"laurentbrieu/tcpdf": "dev-master"` in `composer.json`
2. Run command `composer update`. Package installed successfully. 
3. Added following function in controller:

```
public function TestPDF(){
    $pdf = new tcpdf();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('times','B',16);
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
    $pdf->Output('example_001.pdf', 'I');
}
```

I also checked `autoload_classmap.php` and found lines for tcpdf. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the class is loaded, things are treated a bit differently by Laravel's IOC container. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15225170/2633249) posted to a similar question for a better explanation than I could have given. You should be able to adapt one of the various methods for this package. I'd recommend going the ServiceProvider route described therein.