# How to adapt any package from packagist for Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, package

I need to use the package in my Laravel application (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php). But it is created not specifically for Laravel. How can I adapt this or any other package from packagist for Laravel 5? I suppose I need some ServiceContainer and Facade...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can load any php package with composer autoload.php. It help you to autoload all packages either build for laravel or non-laravel, after installation package with composer you can call or import these packages in your controller or model with **use** keywoard here is an example to call elasticsearch package class

```
use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;

class Post extends Controller{

  public function index(){
    $client = ClientBuilder::create()->build();
  }

}
```

in above example you are not autoloading serviceProvider or facades, composer autoload solves your all problems. read more about **use** keywoard

http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: So, no need to create service provider?? The only thing I can do to simplify using of package is to create Facade for not to use construction 'use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder'?

Comment: yes no need to create service provider, yes you can create Facade than you can statically call ClientBuilder class, i think if you create Facade it will be extra work for you, why not just simply import with 'use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder' you can read here how to create facade http://www.n0impossible.com/article/how-to-create-facade-on-laravel-51

Comment: Ok. I'll use your variant. But for better understanding... Why for any other packages people make service providers? In what cases it is worth it?

Answer (score -1):

[Using third party composer packages with Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15225170/2169355)

**Note**: Although this is an answer for Laravel 4. But I am sure it can help you figuring out what you want to achieve.

Comment: Answers which only contain a link are not good. If the site goes down your answer has no value whatsoever. Please also provide a solution for the question.